# how to merge x axis and y axis data for showing line chart in apex charts using type script

Tags: angular, typescript, apexcharts

i want to merge 2 arrays for creating series data. not able to create series data with epoch time and values.line chart is not creating due to inproper array creation. i need data like below

> [[1327359600000,30.95],[1327446000000,31.34]]

```
 onYAxisItemSelection(item: any): void {
    this.chartOptions.series = [this.chartOptions.series,this.originalSeries.filter(x => x.name == item.item_text).map(x => x.value)];
    //this.chartOptions.series=[{data: [[1327359600000,30.95],[1327446000000,31.34]]
```

im getting the data like
[image: code]